# Неправильное расположение товаров в каталоге Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Здравстуйте.... Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня получается так, что в первой строчке каталога товаров делается пробел, после первых двух или первого одного товара??? Вот Настройки : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужно, чтобы товары были выложены равномерно, по очереди, а не так, как на скрине, когда после первых двух, или первых трёх товаров делается пробел, а далее с новой строки.... Подскажите, где искать настройки, или какие свойства нужно менять в коде.... Спасибо....
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

нужно смотреть шаблон вывода и ксс этой страницы. параметры вызова тут не нужны

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ более развёрнутым описанием решения. Сейчас ваш ответ выглядит, как комментарий.

Comment: @Grimon, не найти так (

Comment: для начала посмотрите верстку. может программист специально верстал так, чтобы в первой строчке было на 1 элемент меньше чем в последующих. а вы начинаете искать зачем то в параметрах вызова. найдите шаблон который вызывается.

Comment: Откройте исходный код этого блока, и скопируйте его в вопрос. Можно будет, для начала, понять, табличная там верстка или блочная.